# Master DNS cannot be resolved when using nsupdate

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, ddns, nsupdate

I want to register a client at a local DNS-Server using nsupdate (Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 jessie 4.1.19-v7+)

```
> nsupdate -d  
> update add lea02.example.local 600 a 10.132.34.32
```

The Response from server fails strangely at resolving its own Name:

```
Reply from SOA query:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id:  17737
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUESTION: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;lea02.example.local.      IN      SOA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.local.       1200    IN      SOA     srvns01.example.local. hostmaster.example.local. 1612344 900 600 1209600 1200

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
srvns01.example.local. 1200 IN A       10.132.34.71

Found zone name: example.local
The master is: srvns01.example.local
couldn't get address for 'srvns01.example.local': not found
```

but a simple nslookup does not indicate a problem here:

```
> nslookup srvns01.example.local

Server:         10.132.34.71
Address:        10.132.34.71#53

Name:   srvns01.example.local
Address: 10.132.34.71
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please read [How do I ask a good question](//serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to rewrite your question so that it matches the site quidelines. Include the following: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? **What does your config look like?** Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?